# How can I order my Firebase array according to data in another node?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some denormalized entities in Firebase, something like this:

```
projects
  -KFsomething
    name: "foo"
  -KFwhatever
    name: "bar"
users
  UID-1234
    name: "Bob"
  UID-5678
    name: "Alice"
observations
  -KFblah
    project: -KFwhatever
    user: UID-1234
    timestamp: 1234567890
  -KFrandom
    project: -KFsomething
    user: UID-5678
    timestamp: 1234567899
```

and so on, with other children. There are other entities with similar relationships. I need to be able to show lists of users, or projects, or other things on a web page sorted by *their most recent associated observation*. So users would be sorted Alice then Bob, because Alice has the newer observation. Likewise projects would be sorted foo then bar, since the newer observation belongs to foo.

How can I do this with denormalized data? The parameter determining sort order does not belong to the objects being sorted. Is there something I can do with the data to make it easier, or do I need some multi-step client side queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NoSQL you'll often need to model your data to allow the way you want to use it. Since you are looking to show users by their most recent observation, you should store the timestamp of the most recent observation for each user.

```
projects
  -KFsomething
    name: "foo"
    mostRecentObservationTimestamp: 1234567899
  -KFwhatever
    name: "bar"
    mostRecentObservationTimestamp: 1234567890
users
  UID-1234
    name: "Bob"
    mostRecentObservationTimestamp: 1234567890
  UID-5678
    name: "Alice"
    mostRecentObservationTimestamp: 1234567899
observations
  -KFblah
    project: -KFwhatever
    user: UID-1234
    timestamp: 1234567890
  -KFrandom
    project: -KFsomething
    user: UID-5678
    timestamp: 1234567899
```

You'll typically write that extra information while you're posting the new observation, with a multi-location update:

```
var observation = {
    project: "-KFsomething",
    user: "UID-5678"
    timestamp: 1234567899
};
var updates = {};
var key = ref.push().key();
updates['observations/'+key] = observation;
updates['users/'+observation.user+'/mostRecentObservationTimestamp'] = observation.timestamp;
updates['projects/'+observation.project+'/mostRecentObservationTimestamp'] = observation.timestamp;
ref.update(updates);
```

See this great [blog post on client-side fan-out](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html).

Comment: I was just coming to this conclusion myself. Nice to know I was on the right track.